# How to put UIImage in front of UILabel - Swift

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel that states where the User if from (location) and i want to put a small icon in from of the text.

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage(named: "geolocationIcon")
let attachmentString:NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
let myString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: location + " ")
myString.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)
otherUserLocationLabel.attributedText = myString
```

and it currently shows like this

[http://s16.postimg.org/vsnd8v5g1/UILABEL.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ8tw.jpg)

How do i put the icon in front of the text ?
Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I ended up creating a Custom UIButton and then simply added the UIImage and Text as follows.

```
            otherUserLocationButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "geolocationIcon"), forState: .Normal)
            otherUserLocationButton.setTitle(" " + location, forState: .Normal)
```

Comment: you can achieve this using `UIButton` by setting its `titleInset` and `imageInset` property.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara Thank you, it was much simpler then i thought.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(50, 50, 300, 21))
    label.center = CGPointMake(160, 284)
    [![label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center][1]][1]
    label.text = "Location text"
    label.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
    label.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "image_name")!

    var bgImage: UIImageView?
    bgImage = UIImageView(image: image)
    bgImage!.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)

    label.addSubview(bgImage!)

    self.view.addSubview(label)
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, this is what i was looking for, thank you ! I've updated my post with another solution as well.